# Can't insert multiple data against an id into multiple fields in a table in mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

**Scenario:** I have a form in my PHP page, inserting data into mySQL database.

Suppose, to each types of T-shirt, there are color variations, size variations and others like this. So in my database, I want to store the data like this:

```
    ---+------+--------+---------
    id | p_id | colors | random
    ---+------+--------+---------
     1 |   1  |   red  |   400
     2 |   1  |  green |   400
     3 |   1  | orange |   400
     4 |   2  |  green |   200
     5 |   2  |  blue  |   200
    ---+------+--------+---------
```

and I'm using a form like this:

```
    Product id     | color                             | random
    ---------------+-----------------------------------+----------
    [Product 1 [v] | [+]Red [+]Green [+]Orange [o]Blue | [    400]
    ---------------+-----------------------------------+----------
```

**Legend:** `[+]` & [o] are checkboxes, `[v]` is a dropdown menu, and `[  ]` is a textbox.

But each time I post the form, it inserts like this:

```
    ---+------+--------+---------
    id | p_id | colors | random
    ---+------+--------+---------
     1 |   1  |   red  |   400
     2 |   1  |  green |   
     3 |   1  | orange |   
    ---+------+--------+---------
```

How can I insert the "random" number into all the three rows?

Comment: post some code or we have guess your code

Comment: Code won't match exactly the scenario, but [here](http://pastebin.com/FA83nznK) are they.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess i understood your problem and post this solution.Put you color checkbox field in an array like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Red"/>Red
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Green"/>Green
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Orange"/>Orange
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Blue"/>Blue
```

Now if you post the form you will get an array of colors with only checked check boxes. For example if you checked red and orange then the array will be like:

```
Array ([color] => Array ( [0] => Red [1] => Orange ))
```

Now you can run a loop here to insert values in your database.

```
<?php
    let,$random=$_POST['random']; 
        $p_id=$_POST['p_id'];
        $colors=$_POST['color'];

    foreach($colors as $each)
    {
        INSERT INTO `shirts`(`p_id`, `colors`, `random`) VALUES ($p_id, $each, $random);
    }
?>
```

Hopefully it will help you.Please ask me if you face any problem.

Comment: Feeling great that it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

It would be really helpful, if you could post your MySQL statement used for inserting the data.
The canonical way would be:

```
INSERT INTO `shirts`(`p_id`, `colors`, `random`) VALUES (1, 'red', 400), (1, 'green', 400), (1, 'orange', 400);
```

Comment: This is a raw SQL query. I'm using a PHP form. :)